# Root directory permission changed

Tags: permissions, sudo, filesystem

i just typed "sudo chmod 744 /" and by mistake i hit the enter button

Now every time I run sudo command I get "Permission Denied" error

bash: /usr/bin/sudo: permission denied

I think the / directory permission was changed by mistake

do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: Yes  thanks for the help. my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Boot to a distro on USB then open a bash shell and correct it there.  Be careful as booting to USB will result is different /dev/sd_